# How to insert character before and after highlighted text in WORD with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlight

I have some highlighted sections in a WORD document that I'm looking to aggregate into a new document, but I'd like to insert a pipe (shift backslash) before and after each unique highlighted section to facilitate import into another program.

I've been able to select and copy these highlighted sections into the new document with the following process:

Find > Advanced Find > More > Format > Highlight > Find in > Main Document > Close > Ctl+C > Ctl+N > Ctl+V

That process puts all of just my highlighted text into a new document.

My end goal is to have those same highlighted sections surrounded by the pipe characters.

I hope this clearly explains my "end game". Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Your title and tags mention VBA. Have you tried anything yet, including the macro recorder? Even sharing recorded code will avoid others having to recreate from scratch.

Comment: No code yet, as I can't figure out where to insert the code for each piece of "extracted" text. I can run the macro recorder as I perform the above steps, but not sure how to format it here - as this is my first post.

Comment: Just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53507112/edit) your post with the code and use the braces or Ctrl-K to format.

Comment: Thanks BigBen... I have this noted for future posts.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like the following code:

```
Sub CopyHighlightedText()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim str As String

    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range

    With rng.Find

        .ClearFormatting
        .Highlight = True

        While .Execute(Forward:=True, Format:=True)
            str = str & " | " & rng.Text
        Wend

    End With

    Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument
    Selection.TypeText Text:=str

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the post... it almost works the way I'm looking for - the only missing piece is the pipe at the end of each selection. Would you be able to post a code update? Thanks so much!

Comment: @MikeDuffy - just add & " | " after rng.Text